# How to checkout a remote branch, rebase it to local master and then merge with local master?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-checkout

A project of mine, on GitHub, has been receiving merge requests from another person, lately. This is awesome, but I am being forced to learn how to manage these requests when conflicts arise. The first few merge requests could be automatically merged by GitHub, so I had to do nothing. The latest one has a conflict, because his changes were made and submitted on top of an older commit of mine. I made changes to the repository after he had checked it out, so his is older than mine and cannot be automatically merged.

I'm trying to resolve this by checking out his branch, rebase it to the current local master and then merge it into my local master.

So, I add his repository as a remote. I then try to checkout his repository, but when I look at the code in his repository it does not reflect what I see of his code on GitHub. I just see a clone of my own local master. Here's a pseudo-run-down of what I'm doing:

```
git remote add person git://path/to/his/repo.git
git checkout -b person/master
git fetch person
```

After that, I can see his branch when I run `git branch -r`. His branch is named `person/master`. I then try `git checkout -b person/master`. I look at the code in his branch expecting to see his changed code, but I just see my own code. When I look at his `person/master` branch on his fork on his Github page, I see changes he has made that are not being reflected in my checkout.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe his pull request doesn't come from `master`.  Don't you have a hash you can use?

Comment: It says he wants to merge commits from his `master`. There is a hash on his commit. I am not sure how to use it, yet.

Comment: What does `git branch --contains THATHASH` say?

Comment: Doesn't show anything. No output. I'm thinking the branch I'm checking out is not actually the one from his repository.

Comment: Seems that way, yes.  Did you `git remote update` to get all of his commits?  How about `git log THATHASH`?

Comment: I did run `git remote update`, and it says it's fetching his remote. Running `git log THATHASH` shows his commit message for the commits I am looking for, though when I `git checkout` his `person/master` branch I do not see the changes he commited.

Comment: Then you should be able to cherry-pick/rebase the ones you care about regardless of symbolic branch name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote add person git://path/to/his/repo.git
git checkout -b person/master
git fetch person
```

I would rather fetch first, then checkout:

```
git remote add person git://path/to/his/repo.git
git fetch person
git checkout -b person/master
```

But one of the idea behind pull requests is that they should be applied automatically... or "put on hold" ;)
In other words, the contributors ought to do the work for you, then submit an updated pull request for you to apply.